# jwplayer not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: video, html5-video, jwplayer

Having issues with jwplayer in Internet Explorer

JW Player version: 6.1.2972

```
<div id="mediaplayer_1294">JW Player goes here</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("mediaplayer_1294").setup({
flashplayer: "jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
file: "media.php?file=encoded_2012-10-19_17.13.24_1360841686.mp4&folder=shareddocs&user=9759",
image: "media.php?file=encoded_2012-10-19_17.13.24_1360841686.jpg&folder=thumb&user=9759",
controlbar: "bottom",
width: "380",
height: "200",
primary: "html5",
type: "mp4",
controls: true,
allowscriptaccess: 'always',
bufferlength: 5
});
</script>
```

**ie7**: It loads and plays fine but I get this on the console

```
LOG: Could not add internal listener
```

**ie8**:

```
Error loading player: Could not load player configuration
```

**ie9**:

```
Error loading media: File could not be played
```

And I get this on the console:

```
LOG: Error playing media: [object MediaError] 
LOG: CAPTIONS([object Object]) 
LOG: CAPTIONS([object Object])
```

Works fine in all other browsers

**UPDATE:**

As i had many jwplayers in one page (10 max) I implemented a click to load the players.
For some reason this has fixed the ie 8 issue

```
<div class="player-<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>">
<div id="mediaplayer_<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>"></div>
<a href="#player-<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>" id="btn_<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb_path; ?>"/></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn_<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
jwplayer('mediaplayer_<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>').setup({
flashplayer: "jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
file: "<?php echo $flv_path; ?>",
image: "<?php echo $thumb_path; ?>",
controlbar: "bottom",
width: "380",
height: "200",
autostart: "true",
primary: "html5",
type: "mp4",
controls: true,
allowscriptaccess: 'always'
});
jwplayer('mediaplayer_<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>').load();
setTimeout(function(){$(".player-<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>").focus();return false;},100);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: 1) Update to 6.2, which has been released.

2) Regarding the IE9 issues, I am fairly certain it has to do with your MIME TYPE, but to confirm this, do you have a link?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..... I have updated to 6.2.3115 and MIME TYPE is set to header('Content-Type: video/mp4'); Retested after update and still the same. Its all password protected so cant give you a link, any other suggestions

Comment: That should be fine. I would probably need to see a link in order to see what is going on though. Can you send it through this way? - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us

Comment: works in ie 8 now after doing a link and click to load the player instead.... see updated question. still the same in ie9

Comment: I would still like to see a link to so I can check why it is failing in IE9. I provided a contact us page.

Answer (score 2):

check the Response header when it calls the .MP4 file.

Make sure you are sending `Content-Length:` in your response. IE9 was failing to load videos until the `content-length` response header was added to the config.

also `Transfer-Encoding:chunked` can mess things up too, which is common if you are gzipping the MP4 file.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with IE, you can use a player state sniffer like the attached below.
When the player is ready for effective event listener subscribtions,
the state turn from undefined to a string value, ( 'IDLE' ).

Then you can attach event listeners when detect this status change.

I guess this is a solution that must be inside of jwplayer code. :)
I am using version 5.9.2156.

```
//Use as an exambple, it may be buggy.
var
    MyObj = {
        pool: 50,
        interval: null,
        videoElement: jwplayer( 'videoAd' ),
        attachEvents: function () {
            this.interval = window.setInterval ( _.bind( function () {
            if ( this.videoElement ) {
                var
                    state = this.videoElement.getState();

                if ( typeof state !== 'undefined' ) {
                    window.clearInterval ( this.interval );
                    this.videoElement
                    .onError( function () { console.log( 'jwplayer: onError' ) } )
                    .onReady( function () { console.log( 'jwplayer: onReady' ) } )
                    .onPlay( function () { console.log( 'jwplayer: onPlay' ) } )
                    .onComplete( function () { console.log( 'jwplayer: onComplete' ) } );
                }
            }
        }, this ), this.pool );
    }
};

MyObj.attachEvents();
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbed upon the same today. I tried to compile the video over and over again. But still only working in Chrome, but not Internet Explorer of Firefox.

Than i found out to change the MIME type in IIS for mp4 from video/mpeg to video/mp4

that worked perfect :)